# Warning: no default GPU device available

Tags: gpu

How do I set my GPU as the default device in Tensor Flow?

It’s an Nvidia GeForce 730 - I’m running Ubuntu.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a screenshot of the (entire) errors that you're received so far? More information would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can use `tf.device('/gpu:id')` to specify a device other than the default.

However, if you are running multiple TensorFlow programs on the same machine, it is recommended that you set the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable to expose different GPUs before starting the processes.